# How to serve static files real-time in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to serve static image files from /static/image/ dynamically.

I'm handling files with Files.copy method to save and replace image files.

```
Files.copy(imageFile.getInputStream(), Paths.get(imageDirectory, filename), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Locally, I can check the file is replaced. However, the server doesn't serve the replaced image even if I refresh the page with Ctrl+Shift+R(Force Refreshing).

To solve this problem, I thought it is problem of caching in server side.
So I set WebConfig and application.properties to disable caching.

```
// WebConfig.java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/image/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/image/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

In application.properties,

```
spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store=true
spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-cache=true
spring.web.resources.cache.period=0
```

```
// ProductService.java
private void saveImageFile(MultipartFile imageFile, String filename) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(imageFile.getInputStream(), Paths.get(imageDirectory, filename), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

public void replaceImageFile(Product product, MultipartFile imageFile) {
   if (imageFile != null && !imageFile.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            String originalFilename = imageFile.getOriginalFilename();
            String fileExtension = originalFilename.substring(originalFilename.lastIndexOf("."));
            String imageName = product.getName().replaceAll("\\s+", "_") + fileExtension;
            saveImageFile(imageFile, imageName);
            product.setImage_name(imageName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, the server still requires restart to serve the replaced and new file. I can't find out what is the problem.

Comment: you need to store the images OUTSIDE of your project folder for this to work. Otherwise it will only work locally with IDE but won't work once it is built as a jar (cause jar is basically a zip and you can't change it once it is deployed). Could this be the issue?